Mandolin restringing
I am wondering how to change mandolin strings? I know, I know, YouTube is my friend for this, but it seems to me, if I leave the slack they tell me to leave, (pull back 1 fret,) I do pull back a fret, and 2 for the plain strings, but I still find the E string to break, i guess should i just measure 1/2 the string? Sorry if I don't make sense, I'm trying to explain as best I can,

If anything is breaking then surely you’re tuning too high?

when you talk about “leave slack,“ I think you’re talking about how much you pull through the peg before you start turning the peg? The only impact of that would be how much is wound around the peg, not the overall intention of the string. The tension is determined by the pitch you tune to. Are you using a tuner?

If the string consistently breaks in the same place it is possible you have a tiny burr in either the bridge or nut. Check for that

Since you mentioned Youtube, I tried watching the first video from the query how to restring mandolin pull back fret and found this:



"Leaving slack" like this wouldn't have anything to do with strings breaking. Once you start tuning, the string will be stretched to the same tension no matter what. All that pulling some back through the peg before you start winding does is put a few more turns of string onto the peg, potentially helping make sure it doesn't slip.
So this becomes simply a "why does my string keep breaking" question.

The most common reason when people are new to tuning is simply tuning the string too high. How confident are you that you're tuning to the right pitch? If you're less than 100% confident, have someone knowledgeable watch while you try.
As mentioned in the comments, if the break is usually in the same place, check for physical there, like at the peg, nut, bridge, or tailpiece.
Is it possible you've just got crappy strings? Are they cheap no-names? Do they seem noticeably thinner than the ones you took off? Spring for one of the common brands.


It may be a burr, Next time I go to guitar center I may bring my guitar and see what $8 can get me setup wise lol. But when I go there to play my dream instruments, I'll have them take a look at it, ik the 1st E slot is too low, Alvarez artist elite 5220 is discontinued so no specs
